# Dynamically create EditorFor using Jquery...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if there was some way to create EditorFor textboxes dynamically when selecting a value in a dropdown list. Here is the example in html/javascript that I found:

http://jsfiddle.net/JvqTW/3/

I'm hoping it will just be a minor tweak to the above example. My issue is that I would still like to use the model values. So, if I select a value from the dropdown, we'll say 3, it will dynamically create the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerText)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerText2)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerText3)
```

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor()` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the client so changing a value in a dropdown will not generate this. You will need to use javascript/jquery to generate your html

Comment: You have to do this on the server. Add a method in your controller that returns a new partial view that you inject via AJAX.

Comment: So, you are saying to create the html tags and take the text of each and set the input text to the model values in the controller, @StephenMuecke?

Comment: Here's the guide I used to do this way back when http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ the fundamentals probably still work in whatever the current MVC is.

Comment: @AndroidianSlip, There are numerous ways you could do this. For example, render all the values inside hidden elements using `@Html.EditorFor()` and display them based on the selection, or make a ajax call that returns a partial view based on the selection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, I forgot to respond. I went with hiding the elements on the page and showing them based on the selection so I didn't have to deal with passing the partialview data around